# Triangle $ABC$ is isosceles with $AB=AC$, and $D$ is the midpoint of $AB$. If $\angle{BCD}=\angle{BAC}=θ$, then $\cos θ$ equals...?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> Triangle $ABC$ is isosceles with $AB=AC$, and $D$ is the midpoint of $AB$. If  $\angle{BCD}=\angle{BAC}=θ$, then $\cos θ$ equals...?

I was doing some UKMT past paper questions - this question is no. 15 from the 1997 Senior Challenge. The answer is 3/4 and in it states that CBD is isosceles with the same angles as ACB. Why is this, and can someone please explain the rest of the question to me too? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AB=AC=2 units. ABC, CDB are isosceles similar triangles.

[image]

Drop a perpendicular from C to side AB at E. DE= EB = $\frac12$

$$\cos \theta = \frac{AE}{AC}=\frac{1+1/2}{2}=\frac34. $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=\angle{ABC}$. Then, $\angle{ACD}=\angle{ACB}-\angle{DCB}=\alpha-\theta$, so we have
$$\angle{CDB}=\angle{BAC}+\angle{ACD}=\theta+(\alpha-\theta)=\alpha.$$
Thus, we know that $\triangle{ABC}$ and $\triangle{CBD}$ are similar.

Let $DB=a$. Then, we have
$$AB:CB=CB:DB$$$$2a:CB=CB:a$$$$CB=\sqrt 2\ a.$$
By the law of cosines for $\triangle{CBD}$ with $CB=CD=\sqrt 2\ a,BD=a$,
$$\cos\theta=\cos\angle{DCB}=\frac{(\sqrt 2\ a)^2+(\sqrt 2\ a)^2-a^2}{2\times (\sqrt 2\ a)^2}=\frac 34.$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\angle BDC = 180 - \angle DBC - \angle BCD = 180 - \angle ABC -\angle BAC = \angle BCA = \angle CBA = \angle CBD$$.

Then, CDB is isosceles with $CB=CD$.

Taking $CH \bot BD$, where $H \in BD$, then $$BH=DH = \frac{1}{2}BD = \frac{1}{4}BA.$$

Finally, one has $$\cos \theta = \frac{AH}{AC} =\frac{AD + DH}{AC} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}AC + \frac{1}{4}AC}{AC} = \frac{3}{4} $$

Answer (score 0):

$\angle ACB=90^\circ-\frac{\theta}{2}$

$\therefore \angle ACD=90^\circ-\frac{3\theta}{2}$

$\therefore \angle ADC=90^\circ+\frac{\theta}{2}$

$\therefore \angle BDC=90^\circ-\frac{\theta}{2}$

$\therefore \triangle BDC$ is isosceles, therefore the perpendicular on $AB$ to $C$ bisects $DB$.

If $|AB|=1$, $\cos\theta=\frac34$.